# Should I run the EE Install & Update Wizard after updating mySQL

Tags: ee2, mysql, update

We are currently running EE v2.7.3.

Our IT partners have informed us that they will be updating the server this week.

They will also be updating Linux, PHP, httpd, and mysql-server moving up to the following versions.

Redhat 6.6 
php-5.3.3-38.el6-x86_64 
httpd-2.2.15-39.el6-x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5-x86_64

I saw the system requirements on the website, but they don’t mention which version of Redhat EE is compatible with.  We’ve run into issues before when updating EE so we want to be cautious and aware of any issues we may run into if any.

Currently our IT folks have updated one of our load balanced servers with newer versions of the redhat, php, mysql.  However, when i try to login to EE Control Panel, I’m getting the installation and update wizard screen.  I'm thinking this is a result of MySQL being updated, but i am not sure.

I'm hesistant to click the "click here to begin!" button because i don't have direct access to the database (I've got a request in to make a backup of the database).

Can someone let me know what should happen after I click “Click here to begin!” button?

I am wondering if this is normal or should i be concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran the updates on our server and we didn't run into any problems.  It seems EE v2.7.3 is compatible with all of these versions of Redhat, PHP, & MySQL.